# Sort a list that was imported from a file... Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to python, and I am hoping I didnt miss a fix for this somewhere else. I have a simple program that was one of the practice excercises in a book I purchased and I am running into an issue. I have a program that opens a file and writes it to a list. Then a user can update the list with input, and when a user exits it updates the list with the latest content. Everything works fine except the sort option. It shows the scores from the file with a single quote infront of them, and the scores updated while the program was running without. It also doesn't sort them at all. I have tried many different way to do this without fail. I am sure this is not that important in the long run, but I wanted to figure it out.

Here is the code

```
# High Scores
# Demonstrates list methods

scores = []
try:
    text_file = open("scores.txt", "r")
    for line in text_file:
        scores.append(line.rstrip("\n"))

    text_file.close()

except:
    raw_input("Please verify that scores.txt is placed in the correct location and run again")



choice = None
while choice != "0":


    print \
    """
    High Scores Keeper

    0 - Exit
    1 - Show Scores 
    2 - Add a Score
    3 - Delete a Score 
    4 - Sort Scores
    """

    choice = raw_input("Choice: ")
    print

    # exit
    if choice == "0":
        try:
            output_file = open("scores.txt" , "w")
            for i in scores:
                output_file.write(str(i))
                output_file.write("\n")

            output_file.close()
            print "Good-bye"
        except:
            print "Good-bye.error"

    # list high-score table
    elif choice == "1":
        print "High Scores"
        for score in scores:
            print score

    # add a score
    elif choice == "2":
        score = int(raw_input("What score did you get?: "))
        scores.append(score)

    # delete a score
    elif choice == "3":
        score = int(raw_input("Delete which score?: "))
        if score in scores:
            scores.remove(score)
        else:
            print score, "isn't in the high scores list."

    # sort scores
    elif choice == "4":
        scores.sort()
        scores.reverse()
        print scores

    # some unknown choice
    else:
        print "Sorry, but", choice, "isn't a valid choice."


raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add scores from the file, you're adding them as strings: `scores.append(line.rstrip("\n"))`. But when you add scores during the program, you're adding them as integers: `int(raw_input("What score did you get?: "))`.

When Python sorts a list containing both strings and integers, it'll sort the strings according to character order (so `'1' < '12' < '3'`), and sort the integers separately, putting the integers before the strings:

```
>>> sorted([1, 8, '11', '3', '8'])
[1, 8, '11', '3', '8']
```

Presumably it's printing out a single quote after the characters as well as before, as it does here (indicating that it's a string).

So, when you're reading the file at the start, turn them into an integer just like you do when you read user input.

---

Some other tips:

- `scores.sort(reverse=True)` will sort in reverse order without having to go through the list twice.
- It's generally a bad idea to do `except:`: that'll catch absolutely any problem with the program, including the user hitting `^C` to try to quit, the system running out of memory, etc. You should do `except Exception:` as a catch-all to get exceptions that it's possible to recover from but not those kinds of system errors, or a more specific exception when you want to handle only certain types.

Comment: Thanks Dougal that work perfectly! What a quick answer, I love this site. It was my first post, but I have used it alot. I have another question. I see different version of python, and I not sure which is the best one to learn. I am reading an intro book for a class I am taking(intro to python), but I want to build off this when I am done. Any thoughts? Thank again!

Comment: If you're talking about 2.7 vs 3.*, there's been a lot of that discussion elsewhere, e.g. [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). It depends on what you want to work on; I've just recently switched to 3.2 for most of my own programming (now that the numpy/scipy/matplotlib ecosystem works well on 3), but there are still a lot of packages that only work for 2. They're really not that different, in any case; I'd say stick with 2.7 unless you want to work on a project that uses 3.

Answer (score 1):

If in your text file you have only one score per line, the best way is to change the scores into integers while taking inputs like this.

```
scores = []
try:
    text_file = open("scores.txt", "r")
    for line in text_file:
        scores.append(int(line.strip()))
except:
    text_file.close()
```

Actually the way you are taking inputs is leaving some of your numbers as strings. The best way to deal with these types of problems is to print the array before sorting and look into it. All the best.

Comment: Rashi this is correct, but dougal had already answered it for me! Thanks again!